# I changed the ownership of one of my google drive folders, but it still consumes from my storage

Tags: storage, drive

My google drive storage is running out of space. So, in order to free some space, I created a new google account and transferred the ownership of one of the largest folders in my original drive (~7 GB) to the new account's drive.

The problem is, that after 3 days of waiting, the folder is still consuming the storage of the original account's drive. I made sure that the new account is the owner of the folder, but the problem is still there.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that changing the ownership of folder inside google drive does not change it for the subfolders and files, you have to change them separately or write an app script to search for file and subfolders owned by you and change the ownership.

Run the script below as your account, if you are using Google Workspace and you are the admin and need to do it to other accounts, then you need to get a service account first and run the code below.

Note:
This way makes a lot of noise with notifications on both sides, the old owner and the new one.

```
    function ChangeFileOwnership(folder){
    // New owner
    var new_owner = '<Add new owner email>';
    if (folder == null) {
      var folderObj = DriveApp.getFolderById('<ID of parent folder>');
      return ChangeFileOwnership(folderObj);
    }
    var fileIt = folder.searchFiles('"me" in owners');
    while (fileIt.hasNext()) {
      var file = fileIt.next();
      Logger.log("Changing ownership of " + file.getName() + " to " + new_owner);
      // Set the owner to be the new owner
      try {
          file.addEditor(new_owner);
      }
      catch(err){
          Logger.log(err.message);
      }
      try { 
          file.setOwner(new_owner);
      }
      catch(err){
        Logger.log(err.message); 
      }
    }
    // Get all the sub-folders and iterate
    var folderIt = folder.getFolders();
    while (folderIt.hasNext()) {
      fs = ChangeFileOwnership(folderIt.next());
    }
  }
```